# gulp-eslint not linting even though eslint directly is linting correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, eslint, gulp-eslint

I have a project that shows an error when linting without gulp, but fails to show the same error when linting via gulp-eslint.

gulpfile.js

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const inject = require('gulp-inject');  // Should error since this is never used
const eslint = require('gulp-eslint');

// Common paths
const paths = {
  index: './index.html',
  dist: './dist',
  js: '**/*.js',
  nodeModules: 'nodeModules/**'
};

gulp.task('default', ['lint'], function() {
  // place code for your default task here
});

gulp.task('lint', function() {
  return gulp.src([paths.js, '!' + paths.nodeModules])
    .pipe(eslint())
    .pipe(eslint.format())
    .pipe(eslint.failAfterError());
});
```

.eslintrc.json

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true
  },
  "extends": "eslint:recommended",
  "parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "globals": {
    "require": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "indent": ["error", 2],
    "linebreak-style": ["error", "unix"],
    "quotes": ["error", "single"],
    "semi": ["error", "always"],
    "strict": ["error", "safe"]
  }
}
```

eslint directly works, but not via gulp task

```
$ eslint gulpfile.js 

gulpfile.js
  3:7  error  'inject' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

$ gulp lint
[12:13:29] Using gulpfile ~/Sites/myproject/gulpfile.js
[12:13:29] Starting 'lint'...
[12:13:29] Finished 'lint' after 35 ms
```

project structure

```
- eslintrc.json
- gulpfile.js
```

Why does my gulp task not lint properly?

**EDIT**

Seems that if I change to paths.js below, it lints all files in any subdir

```
const paths = {
  js: '*/*.js',
};
```

If i change to paths.js below, it lints all files in the current dir

```
const paths = {
  js: '*.js',
};
```

I'm a bit puzzled why  `**/*.js` doesn't lint anything?

Comment: Works for me... maybe some problem with versions? I have gulp 3.9.1, gulp-eslint 3.0.1, gulp-inject 4.2.0 running under node 6.9.1 and npm 3.10.8

Comment: Does it print out an error for you?

Comment: ESLint correctly reports the `no-unused-vars` error when I run `gulp lint`

Comment: Hmm yea that's what I would expect. Here's the version i'm using: ` $ npm list --depth=0
├── eslint@3.16.0
├── gulp@3.9.1
├── gulp-eslint@3.0.1
├── gulp-inject@4.2.0
└── wiredep@4.0.0
$ node -v
v6.9.1
$ npm -v
3.10.8`

Comment: k, I'm stumped. Only other thing I can think of is maybe delete `node_modules` and reinstall everything.